# Why my Registry pattern implementation not working?

Tags: php, design-patterns

Am I missing something? Or am I misunderstanding the concept?

From my current understanding of the design pattern of Registry, the file test.php should print the name "MIH406", but it didn't! Why?

First I visited index.php page, then I visited test.php page.

Does it work like that?

I want to learn the concept behind Registry whether it is considered good or bad, so please no need to re-open a discussion here about how good or how bad this pattern, thanks.

NOTE: I am testing it under my pc with Ubuntu and LAMP

Here is my simple implementation:

index.php

```
<?php
require_once "registry.php";

Registry::getInstance()->set("name", "MIH1406");
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
require_once "registry.php";

echo Registry::getInstance()->get("name");
?>
```

registry.php

```
<?php
class Registry
{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_registry = array();

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if(self::$_instance == null)
        {
            self::$_instance = new Registry();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function set($key, $value)
    {
        $this->_registry[$key] = $value;
    }

    public function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        if(!isset($this->_registry[$key]))
        {
            return $default;
        }

        return $this->_registry[$key];
    }

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    private function __clone()
    {
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you do not set a value to internal variable.

Having in `set()`:  `$this->registry[$key] = $value;` means you have to have property $registry, but you are having `private $_registry = array();`. So, maybe it's a typo, but $registry != $_registry

---

With your edited code, this works for me. You need to include the files dependently.

index.php:

```
<?php
include 'registry.php';
Registry::getInstance()->set("name", "MIH1406");
?>
```

test.php

```
<?php
include 'index.php';
echo Registry::getInstance()->get("name");
?>
```

Then running `test.php` outputs: `MIH1406`

Comment: that was not my problem. I think there is another problem or I am misunderstanding the concept?

Comment: It works for me, with the changed code, if it's in one file. Running seperately first index.php then test.php won't work, it's not in the same session. You have only to run test.php, and it should include index.php

Comment: that is my concern, do I have to use it within the same session?! From your answer, Yes, I have to!